# How to obtain $\int_0^1|u(x,\tau)|^2 \ dx \le\int_0^1|f|^2 \ dx \qquad (2)$ with $u(x,t)$ solving the 1D Heat Equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x,t)$ solve
$$\begin{cases}
u_t = u_{xx} \quad (0<x<1, t\gt 0)\\
u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0 \\
u(x,0) = f(x)
\end{cases}\quad \ \ (1)$$
for $f\in C[0,1]$. Show that for all $\tau\ge 0$,
$$\int_0^1|u(x,\tau)|^2 \ dx \le\int_0^1|f|^2 \ dx \qquad (2)$$

---

My attempt: As a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, we see that $u(x,t)\le f(x)$ for $x\in [0,1]$. This implies that $u(x,\tau) \downarrow$ on $[0,1]$. Now, we have to prove this claim. This is where my argument breaks down. Looking at the explicit representation formula for $u(x,t)$ satisfying $(1)$, I don’t think this logic is correct.

Is there an inequality that you can apply to attain $(2)$, or am I on the right track? I’m sure that I am missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Seek $u$ in the form
$$
u=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k(t)\sin( k\pi x).
$$
Then $c_k(t)=c_k(0)e^{-k^2t}$ and
$$
\int_0^1|u(x,\tau)|^2dx=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty |c_k(\tau)|^2\le
\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty |c_k(0)|^2=\int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx.
$$

Comment: Why $\int_0^1|u(x,\tau)|^2 \ dx = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|c_k(t)|^2$?

Comment: Because $\int_0^1\sin(k\pi x)\sin(j\pi x)=\frac12\delta_{kj}$

Comment: What do you mean by $\delta_{kj}$? The dirac-delta measure?

Comment: The Kronecker delta $\delta_{kj}=1$ for $k=j$ and $0$ for $k\ne j$.